# Show a form-field dynamically on option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/gyvfun5L/)

I am adding the template ID read-only fields, based on selection of option. 1 for SMS, 2 for email etc..

Since there is a provision to add new category, how to dynamically add template IDs to newly added options?

```
//Adding Template ID based on option
$('#categoryevent').on('click', function() {
  $('.actionConfig').empty();
  var z = $("#categoryevent option:selected").text();  
  if (z == 'sms') {
    var smsConfig = '<div class=form-group><label class="col-sm-2 control-label"for=templateId>Template ID: </label><div class=col-sm-8><input class=form-control id=templateId name=templateId value="1" readonly="readonly"></div></div>';
    $('.actionConfig').append(smsConfig);
  }
});
```

Comment: Well you're already adding the new options to the select tag. What do you want exactly to happen when you select the new option? It's pretty easy to just default to what you're doing for the SMS option, so I would guess you do not want this solution. What **do** you want specifically?

Comment: @Glubus: Template ID field gets added only for the fields that I have coded for and not for the options  added dynamically. So how do I do it?

Comment: Alrght, I'll make an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,
you can do something like this,

Set value of option as Template-Id 1,2,3 now when you add new category maintain counter and add it as value of newly added option.

Now keep other things same just get template id from option value.

something like this,

```
var opval = get option value here..
     var smsConfig = '<div class=form-group><label class="col-sm-2 control-label"for=templateId>Template ID: </label><div class=col-sm-8><input class=form-control id=templateId name=templateId value="+opval+" readonly="readonly"></div></div>';
        $('.actionConfig').append(smsConfig);
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:

[answer jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darsthakkar/33jgyzwv/4/)

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle?

Comment: I hope you understand logic because this platform is for doubt solving not getting direct answers. Though here is fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/darsthakkar/33jgyzwv/3/ I also have edited the same in answer, upvote if worked as needed.

Comment: Type something in the input field and click on "add category" you might see what happens

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/gyvfun5L/1/ Check this out! There are few issues with your code. TemplateID should appear as soon as you add a new category. It is not smooth. It happens only on change!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for the textual representation of the option, you should check for the value attribute. Since you did not add the value attributes yet for the options you hardcoded, you will have to do this as well, i.e. change:

```
<option>SMS</option>
```

to

```
<option value="0">SMS</option>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the standard `value` attribute (e.g. because you want to avoid default beheviour) you can instead go for `<option data-selectionId="1">SMS</option>`. Obviously increment the id for each option you have in your select.

Now if you create a new option, you will have to set this data:

```
  var val = $("#new-option-event").val().trim();
  var opt = '<option value="'+ globalCounterVariable +'">' + val + '</option>';
  globalCounterVariable += 1; 

  $('#categoryevent').append(opt);
  $('#categoryevent').val(val);
  $('#new-option-event').val('');
```

You will have to define a global veriable (actually outside of the scope of the `.addevent` handler is enough) that you initially will have to set to 3 (the number of hardcoded options).

Now you can do this:

```
$('#categoryevent').on('change', function() {
      var selection = $(this).val(); //this is reference to the changed element, i.e. the select with Id 'categoryeveny'. 

      var html = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="templateId">Template ID: </label><div class="col-sm-8"><input class="form-control" id="templateId" name="templateId" readonly="readonly"></div></div>';

      $(html).find("input").val(selection);

      $(".actionConfig").empty();
      $('.actionConfig').append(html);
});
```

Note how I removed the need for all the `if` clauses, because you did the same logic each branch. Simply parameterize whatever you want to inject and this is all you need.

If you want to show different values for each selection (so different data than 1,2,3,... etc), you will have to either make that an option in the input where you create a new option, or hardcode generic logic in the `change` event, where you decide what content is shown based on the value of selection.

Comment: Well check your console log, you or I may have made a syntax error. Don't just say "it doesnt work" and give up. You're developing something, not copy pasting. Are there any errors on the console? Try putting some console logs here and there in order to log the values of different variables.

Comment: Alright well good on you for finding a solution. SelectedIndex is also a great solution. Don't forget to either delete your quesiton or mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer fiddle : [DEMOanswer](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/gyvfun5L/1/)

```
$('#categoryevent').on("click", function(ev) {
        //  alert(ev.target.selectedIndex);
        var value = ev.target.selectedIndex;
        $('.actionConfig').empty();
        var z = $("#categoryevent option:selected").text();

        z = z.toLowerCase();

        var templateId = '<div class=form-group><label class="col-sm-2 control-label"for=templateId>Template ID: </label><div class=col-sm-8><input class=form-control id=templateId value="' + value + '" name=templateId readonly="readonly"></div></div>';
        $('.actionConfig').append(templateId);

    });
```